# Count and mass unsave images on Instagram?

Tags: javascript, selenium, count, instagram

I've been using [instagram unsaver](https://github.com/thisismo/instagram-unsaver) for a while now to unsave all my images on Instagram, and also count how many are them by using the "select all" button. But now the project seems to be read-only, and I'm left with a collection of +500 of art reference saved images, and no way to unsaved them all (Or count if the number I have downloaded are the same as the ones that are saved)

I know Instagram is not fond to open APIs, not anyone messing with browser scripts, but even so my question is: Is there a Python-Selenium script, JS script, userscript, or Firefox/Chrome extension that could allow me to:

1. Count all my saved posts, and if possible, all the saved "images"
   (For those post that are +1 images)
2. Unsave them all, doesn't matter if it takes a while. I know
   Instagram fetches the images using js, so there aren't actually "in
   the browser" until I scroll past them (i.e there isn't a "div" or
   "img" html tag until I actually see them on my viewport)

I'd like to do it manually, but there are so much images it's not even an option at this point.

Edit: I didn't explain what "unsave" is. You can "save" posts in instagram using the bookmark icon on the left of each post. You can have multiple "saved" posts, and delete each one (AKA "unsave") on you saved images from your profile (https://www.instagram.com/USER/saved/)

Comment: What is "unsave"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry, I've edited the question to add that piece of info